# Disable field based on input of another field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to disable a field based on the selection from a dropdown list.

Here's my code so far:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ccVersandkostenTraeger, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ccVersandkostenTraeger, new SelectList(Model.ccVersandkostenTraeger), new { @class = "form-control versandkostentraeger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ccKostenstelle, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ccKostenstelle, new { @class = "form-control kostenstelle" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ccKostenstelle)
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this already:

```
    if ($(".versandkostentraeger").val() != "Absender") {
    $(".kostenstelle").attr("disabled", "true");
}
```

Basically the drop-down list `versandkostentraeger` only has two value to choose from: `Empfänger` or `Absender`.
I want `kostenstelle` to be disabled if `Empfänger` is selected or `Absender` is not selected(I write it like this because I don't know if the 'ä' can be read properly).
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have should work, you just need to place it in a `change` event handler for the `select`. Try this:

```
$('.versandkostentraeger').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "Absender") {
        $(".kostenstelle").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

You could also use `Empfänger` in the condition, so long as your page encoding is set correctly.

Comment: It didn't work with the classes I gave them, so I tried the IDs given from Razor. I Also added an `else` statement because, without it, it stayed disabled after changing back to `Absender`. Now it works fine. Thanks for your fast and helpful answer.